# How to add a scrollbar with LabelFrame in Python (Tkinter)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I would like to know how to add a scrollbar with two LabelFrame in Python (Tkinter)?

Example is as follow:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Laccc.png)

My code:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry('200x500')

labelframe1 = LabelFrame(root, text="Label Frame 1")
labelframe1.place(x=10, y=0, width=100, height=600)

labelframe2 = LabelFrame(root, text="Label Frame 2")
labelframe2.place(x=130, y=0, width=100, height=600)

for i in range(200):
    Label(labelframe1, text=i).grid(row=i, column=0)
    Label(labelframe2, text=i).grid(row=i, column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Thank you.

I would like ti konw how to add a scrollbar with two LabelFrame in Python (Tkinter)?

Comment: please write your code in code snippet

Comment: You *can't* add a scrollbar to a LabelFrame - only a few specific Tkinter widgets support scrolling, and this isn't one of them.  If you look at any Tkinter scrollbar example, you will see that the general approach is to use a Canvas (which *is* scrollable), and add your widget(s) to that Canvas via `.create_window()`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tkinter - Add scrollbar for each LabelFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21429014/tkinter-add-scrollbar-for-each-labelframe)